# How to convert pandas datetime64 into something that can be recognized as DateField by Django?

Tags: python, django, pandas, django-models

When I load an Excel using pandas, the column containing dates was correctly identified as `datetime64`

```py
excel_table = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name=ws_name, header=2) 
print(excel_table['Start Date'])

# output:
0       2001-01-31
1       2001-03-02
2       2001-07-23
3       2001-07-25
4       2002-03-11
...
Name: Start Date, Length: 11056, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Then, I wrote `excel_table` to a sqlite3 database:

```py
excel_table.to_sql(table_name, cols_to_use, index=False)
```

When I inspect the columns using `PRAGMA table_info(TABLENAME)`, I got this:

```
...
11|Start Date|NUM|0||0
...
```

Shouldn't it be `TIMESTAMP` rather than `NUM`?

Then, I generate a model class using Django's `inspectdb` method that gave me this:

```py
# This is an auto-generated Django model module.
# You'll have to do the following manually to clean this up:
#   * Rearrange models' order
#   * Make sure each model has one field with primary_key=True
#   * Make sure each ForeignKey and OneToOneField has `on_delete` set to the desired behavior
#   * Remove `managed = False` lines if you wish to allow Django to create, modify, and delete the table
# Feel free to rename the models, but don't rename db_table values or field names.
from django.db import models


class TableName(models.Model):

    start_date = models.TextField(db_column='Start Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. This field type is a guess.


    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'TableName'
```

Now, it's a `TextField` rather than a `DateField`, which is problematic because I'm trying to implement filtering and sorting features on this column (e.g. filtering dates after 2020-12-31,etc.).

Where have I made mistakes, and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In models.py, declare the `start_date` field as `DateField` (or `DateTimeField`)**

`datetime64` dtype of dataframe will be converted automatically to the corrected type into MySQL or SQLite.

In serializers.py, add the following line:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

start_date = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

---

**Old answer**:

Maybe you can try to convert the `datetime64` to python datetime and export to database:

```
df['Start Date'] = df['Start Date'].dt.to_pydatetime()
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. I actually figured this out. I need to manually change the `TextField` to `DateTimeField` in modes.py

Comment: Thank you. Can you update  your answer to include that to customize the format, I did it in `serializers.py`, where I added `start_date = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%Y-%m-%d")`

Comment: Where does the `serializers` module come from?

Comment: That's the one I built for serializing the SQL data into JSON format so my frontend can query it.

Comment: I mean the `serializers.DateTimeField' not `serializers.py`.

Comment: Yea, that module comes from `from rest_framework import serializers`